Quasi-Lie algebras
A strangest idea is bugging me right now. Lie algebras are vector spaces over some fields that are endowed by Lie brackets. What if, instead of vector spaces over fields, we considered modules over rings, endowed with Lie brackets? This situation I call quasi-Lie algebras, since if ring is a field, we get Lie algebras back. Did anyone do any research with respect to this, or better yet, wrote a book? I have no idea if this idea anywhere exists... It would be fun to see what happens! Thankieeees for info and sowwy if not interesting to you, only to me....

This might interest you https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84255/how-about-the-lie-algebra-over-commutative-ring

Thankies, @YADDADEN! This person asking is nice to everyone, like I wanna be!

Title: They are not called Quasi-Lie algebras, but Lie rings. See for example this post. For quasi-Lie algebras see here, and this MO-post.

@DietrichBurde, I did not know how they are called! Thankieeees!
